# How to write separated Arabic letters?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a program that accepts Arabic letters in EditText and those letters must be not linked together. And as far as I know, Arabic letters are linked together.

Example :   Arabic letters like (كلب) 
            should be like ( ك ل ب)  of-course without spaces between letters

So how can I do to solve this issue or if there are any encodes must be with in XML file?

Comment: Samy, do you want them linked at the end or not? I really don't get your question.

Comment: i want them separated from each other .

Comment: Please see my response below.

Answer (score 4):

As [Porges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892173/how-to-write-separated-arabic-letters#comment26184147_8892241) said, use **"\u200C"** between two linked letters to separate them without **" "**

Answer (score 1):

You can try manually add spaces between each letter using a for-loop by doing something like this:

```
myEditText   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String temp = myEditText.getText().toString();

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
     temp = temp.charAt(i) + " ";
}

myEditText.setText(temp);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i don't want to use spaces between letters .More suggestion please .

Comment: Instead of using spaces you could use the "Zero-Width Non Joiner" character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner

Answer (score 1):

look into this http://www.unicodemap.org/range/85/Arabic_Presentation_Forms-B/ Unicode Map, when the user enters any new character, handle it with replacing the equivalent from the Map

Comment: how can i convert this Arabic Unicode characters to string character ?

Comment: you need to build a Map of current Letters, like letter 'أ = 50' (sample), then look-up then Unicode Map so convert the character to '0xFE83', the best way is get all the string once, then convert it to char[] then replace char by char